# Laravel query builder join not working with selectRaw

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I am using laravel's query builder to fetch locations from my database. I need to join 2 tables then query the results by location. It was all working fine until I added the join.

If I just do

```
$locations = DB::table('locations')
->join('charities', 'locations.charity', '=', 'charities.charity')
    ->when($charity, function ($query) use ($charity) {
          return $query->where('charity', '=', $charity);
    })
    ->get();
```

Then it return the contents of both tables which I need. If I do

```
$locations = DB::table('locations')
            ->select('locations.*')
            ->selectRaw('( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(?) ) *
                               cos( radians( latitude ) )
                               * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(?)
                               ) + sin( radians(?) ) *
                               sin( radians( latitude ) ) )
                             ) AS distance', [$lat, $lng, $lat])
            ->havingRaw("distance < ?", [$max_distance])
            ->when($charity, function ($query) use ($charity) {
                return $query->where('charity', '=', $charity);
            })
            ->get();
```

Then I get the contents of the locations table and the filter works fine.

I put the both together and it only return the content of locations with no error and the charities table not been joined on.

```
$locations = DB::table('locations')
            ->join('charities', 'locations.charity', '=', 'charities.charity')
            ->select('locations.*')
            ->selectRaw('( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(?) ) *
                               cos( radians( latitude ) )
                               * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(?)
                               ) + sin( radians(?) ) *
                               sin( radians( latitude ) ) )
                             ) AS distance', [$lat, $lng, $lat])
            ->havingRaw("distance < ?", [$max_distance])
            ->when($charity, function ($query) use ($charity) {
                return $query->where('charity', '=', $charity);
            })
            ->get();
```

Comment: Try to specify for every column, the name of the table it is coming from.

Comment: The only thing coming from the Charity table is charity name which is already in the locations to do the join on and a charity logo. Everything else comes from the locations tabel

Comment: Sorry didn't read you post properly, I've specified the tables for each column and it works a charm! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After MosCH comment I got it working, Pretty simple fix incase any one else has this issue see my code below. You'll notice I have specified locations.charity in the where clause Because the charity is what I join on I guess it was conflicting.

```
$locations = DB::table('locations')
            ->join('charities', 'locations.charity', '=', 'charities.charity')
            ->select('*')
            ->selectRaw('( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(?) ) *
                               cos( radians( latitude ) )
                               * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(?)
                               ) + sin( radians(?) ) *
                               sin( radians( latitude ) ) )
                             ) AS distance', [$lat, $lng, $lat])
            ->havingRaw("distance < ?", [$max_distance])
            ->when($charity, function ($query) use ($charity) {
                return $query->where('locations.charity', '=', $charity);
            })
            ->get();
```